# How to style a table to encourage some cells grow vertically before horizontally

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have an HTML table, simplified as:

```
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td style='white-space: nowrap;' >alpha alpha alpha </td>
    <td rowspan=3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
    <td>alpha</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style='white-space: nowrap;' >beta beta beta </td>
    <td>beta</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style='white-space: nowrap;' >gamma gamma gamma </td>
    <td>gamma</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1v2h4x9a/

This normally displays as:

[image: normal rendering of HTML table]

I would prefer to have it word wrap to take up the available vertical space.  Thus, it should render as:

[image: desired rendering of HTML table]

The goal here is efficient use of screen real estate.  I.e. Why should the column become wider when there are additional lines to wrap the text in.

Further, I want to do this with HTML and CSS only.  No javascript.  I'm willing to see a javascript based answer (but unlikely to want it).

Note that the real table has multiple columns with varying heights, and the leftmost column staggered from the rest, but it isn't worth showing that in the sample.  Further, I would prefer that the cell grow horizontally if something else hasn't already made vertical space.

I've tried setting the table width small: This results in the second column getting very narrow and pushing the height larger.

Comment: Can you give us a snippet or fiddle to play around with?

Comment: @thingEvery: done.  I extracted the CSS and put classes on things.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think this is possible without only CSS. If you're open to a JS solution, @ me.

Comment: @thingEvery: I will entertain javascript (but am unlikely to like it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right. You won't like it. But here's how you can do it - with jQuery and without. The trick is to wrap the contents of that cell in a div so you have something to measure.

With jQuery:

```js
var cellWidth = 1000;
var tableHeight = $('.c2').innerHeight();
var fontSize = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle($('.c2 span')[0]).fontSize, 10);

do {
 $('.c2').css('width', cellWidth+'px');
 cellWidth-=20;
}
while ( $('.c2 span').innerHeight() < tableHeight - fontSize);

$('.c2').css('width', $('.c2 span').width() );
```

```css
.c2 {
padding: 0 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1 class=t>
  <tr>
    <td class=c1>alpha alpha alpha </td>
    <td class=c2 rowspan=3><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span></td>
    <td class=c3d>alpha</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class=c1>beta beta beta </td>
    <td class=c3>beta</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class=c1>gamma gamma gamma </td>
    <td class=c3>gamma</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Plain JS:

```js
var cellWidth = 1000;
var theCell = document.querySelectorAll('.c2')[0];
var theSpan = document.querySelectorAll('.c2 div')[0];
var cellHeight = theCell.offsetHeight;

do {
 theCell.style.width = cellWidth+'px';
 cellWidth--;
}
while ( theSpan.offsetHeight < cellHeight);
```

```html
<table border=1 class=t>
  <tr>
    <td class=c1>alpha alpha alpha </td>
    <td class=c2 rowspan=3><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div></td>
    <td class=c3d>alpha</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class=c1>beta beta beta </td>
    <td class=c3>beta</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class=c1>gamma gamma gamma </td>
    <td class=c3>gamma</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Edit:** I added an additional line to the jQuery version to subtract the font size from the cell height when comparing against the div height.

**Edit:** Added additional line (in jQuery version) to tighten up spacing, along with some padding for breathing room.

Comment: Viable.  Painful, especially with multiple columns with multiple entries.  The additional clause in jquery makes it stop as soon as it has anything on the last line, but it may be able to go further.  The jquery version also now takes bigger jumps.  The missing entry in the plain JS version is to back the width out by one. It occurs to me, I could probably binary search the size.

Comment: @DavidG. I edited the jQuery version again to remove that extra horizontal space. Hit the check, boyee!

Comment: Well, it worked, despite multiple columns and multiple cells per column.  And using a stylesheet entry per column worked.  And binary search worked.  The only really weird thing is that, if the largest string has no spaces or break points, I wind up finding the width as the minimum (which I set to 50).

Answer (score 0):

How about just setting the table column to a fixed width like so:

```
.c2{
  width:150px;
}
```

or are you looking for it to always take up three lines no matter how much text is in there. I guess I am asking if it is adaptive and you always need it to be three lines, or if you can just play around with the width value until it looks like what you want.

Comment: I'm looking for something that makes efficient use of available space.